# Fourier Transform of cosine in the interval $-\frac{\pi}{2}$ to $\frac{\pi}{2}$

Tags: fourier-transform, piecewise-continuity

Calculate the Fourier transform of the function:

\begin{equation} f(x) = \begin{cases}\cos(x) & \text{ if } \frac{-\pi}{2}\leq x \leq \frac{\pi}{2}\\ 0 &\text{ otherwise.}\end{cases}\end{equation}

What I did was to use the identity:
\begin{equation} \cos(x) = \frac{e^{ix} + e^{-ix}}{2}\end{equation}

I now have this integral (note, by convention I let the constant before the integral be $1$):
\begin{equation}  \int^{\pi/2}_{-\pi/2} \frac{1}{2}\left( e^{-i(\omega-1)x}+ e^{-i(\omega+1)x} \right) \, dx\end{equation}

I have tried solving this many times but I get something totally wrong. The right answer is as follows:

\begin{equation} f(x) = \begin{cases} \frac{2\cos(\pi\omega/2)}{1-\omega^2}), & \text{ if } \omega \neq \pm1\\ \frac{\pi}{2} & \text{ if }\omega = \pm1\end{cases}\end{equation}

Now, I have two questions:

1. How do you get that result, that is, evaluate the integral?
2. Why do we have two answers and why at $\pm1$ (very contra-intuitive number)?

Thank you!

Comment: I don't see where you have a difficulty. Just compute the two integrals  $\int^{\pi/2}_{-\pi/2}  e^{-ax} dx =-\frac1{a}[e^{-ax}] |^{x=\pi/2}_{x=-\pi/2}$ with $a=i\omega \pm i$

Comment: For your second question, have you seen that you have a $0/0$ expression when $\omega=\pi/2$ ?

Comment: A notational detail : your last equation should begin by $\hat{f}(\omega)=...$.

Comment: I get an awfully complicated expression. That's why I think that i cannot use the cos = e identity. I get this:
$\frac{1}{4\pi}\left( \frac{(i-i\omega)(e^{(i\omega - i)\frac{\pi}{2}}-e^{-(i\omega - i)\frac{\pi}{2}}) + (i+i\omega)(e^{(i\omega + i)\frac{\pi}{2}}-e^{-(i\omega + i)\frac{\pi}{2}})}{1-\omega^2} \right )$

And I cannot see how this can ever be simplificated so that it matches the answer given above.

Comment: Please note that $e^{i  \pi/2}=i$ and $e^{-i  \pi/2}=-i$ . For example $e^{i \omega +i \pi/2}$ becomes $ie^{i \omega}$ etc. Afterwards, you should recognize a cosine.

Comment: Thank you incredibly much Marie!